# How to map Data Table to "DTO" using Express Mapper

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, mapper

I am using ASP.NET Web API and C#. As i am new to Express Mapper and i am having ADO.NET code which is returning list of results.How to map using Express Mapper?

Comment: you could implement a custom `ICustomTypeMapper<TSrc, TDest>`

Comment: Can u explain me by writting more lines of code.because i am totally new to this express mapper topic

Comment: Oh, that's your home work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a test to demonstrate how to work with custom mappers in ExpressMapper. I hope you'll be able to use it accordingly -

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var ds = new DataSet();
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
        dt.Rows.Add("Test", 10);
        dt.Rows.Add("Test2", 10);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        var mapped = Mapper.Map<DataTable, List<RequestModel>>(ds.Tables[0], new CustomTypeMapper());

    }
```

where -

```
class RequestModel
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class CustomTypeMapper : ICustomTypeMapper<DataTable, List<RequestModel>>
{
    public List<RequestModel> Map(IMappingContext<DataTable, List<RequestModel>> context)
    {
        if (context.Source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        var output = new List<RequestModel>();
        foreach (DataRow row in context.Source.Rows)
        {
            output.Add(new RequestModel
            {
                Age = row.Field<int>("Age"),
                Name = row.Field<string>("Name")
            });
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```